# Difference between the signatures of Optional.map & Optional.flatMap methods

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I'm able to find out the difference between the `Optional.map` & `Optional.flatMap` and when to use which method. But what I'm not able to understand what is that the difference between the two method's signatures. From the documentation, I found the below.

```
public <U> Optional<U> map(Function<? super T,? extends U> mapper)

public <U> Optional<U> flatMap(Function<? super T, Optional<U>> mapper)
```

Can anyone please explain the difference between `Function<? super T,? extends U>` and `Function<? super T, Optional<U>>` with some example?

Comment: @Christos, I have checked the link that you have shared but that doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Ignoring generics, in `map`, the mapping function returns an object of type `U` whereas in `flatMap`, it returns an `Optional<U>`.